# Classical reference for “vector-valued” Laplace expansion?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, determinant, multilinear-algebra, laplace-expansion

In relation to the $2\times 2$ (say) determinant $$\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{vmatrix},$$ consider the “bordered” determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}
x&a&b\\
x&a&b\\
y&c&d
\end{vmatrix}.$$
It must be zero since the first two rows are equal. Using the Laplace cofactor expansion along the first row, we obtain
$$\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{vmatrix}x=\begin{vmatrix}x&b\\y&d\end{vmatrix}a+\begin{vmatrix}a&x\\c&y\end{vmatrix}b.\tag{1}$$
A similar argument shows
$$\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{vmatrix}y=\begin{vmatrix}x&b\\y&d\end{vmatrix}c+\begin{vmatrix}a&x\\c&y\end{vmatrix}d.\tag{2}$$
Combining (1) and (2) in vector form, we have
$$\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{vmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}x&b\\y&d\end{vmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\c\end{bmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}a&x\\c&y\end{vmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b\\d\end{bmatrix}.\tag{3}$$
Notice also that if we take $x=1$ and $y=0$ in (1), we obtain the cofactor expansion of $\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{vmatrix}$ along the first row, and if we take $x=0$ and $y=1$ in (2), we obtain the cofactor expansion along the second row.

These ideas generalize to $n\times n$ matrices. In fact if $E$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space and $\Delta$ is a determinant function in $E$, then using an $(n+1)$-dimensional cofactor expansion we can prove
$$\Delta(x_1,\ldots,x_n)x=\sum_{j=1}^n\Delta(x_1,\ldots,x,\ldots,x_n)x_j,\tag{4}$$
where $x$ is in the $j$-th position of $\Delta$ on the right. Applying projection operators on both sides of (4) we can recover the $n$-dimensional cofactor expansions.

Does anyone know of a classical source or name for this result? I’ve looked in a number of places including thumbing through Muir and Metzler but haven’t found it. Given the close connection to Laplace, I’ve been calling it a “vector-valued” Laplace expansion, but I’m not sure if it has another name.

Comment: If $\Delta$ is the standard determinant function, then (4) can be equated with Cramer's rule in its non-fractional form (Theorem 6.120 **(a)** in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, arXiv:2008.09862v3](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.09862v3), as I'm too lazy to find a proper historical source). However, of course, it's true for any determinant functional or even any alternating multilinear function. It is probably easier to prove (4) from scratch than to find it in history.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks for the reference! I wasn't thinking of Cramer's rule in that particular non-fractional vector form, but that makes sense.